# Question on measurable function as infinite sum

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

I have a question about a nonnegative Lebesgue measurable function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \cup \{ \infty \} $.

The question asks me to show that $$f= \sum_{n=0}^ \infty f \chi_{f^{-1} ([n, n+1) )} .$$

But unless I’m missing something this is only true for when $f$ is finite valued. If $f(x)= \infty $ then $\chi_{f^{-1} ([n, n+1))}(x)=0 $ for all $n$ so it can’t possibly hold for this $x$.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. Let $x\in[0,1]$. If we have $f(x)<\infty$, then we have $f(x)\chi_{f^{-1}([n,n+1)}(x)=0$ for all $n\neq\lfloor f(x)\rfloor$ since then $f(x)\not\in[n,n+1)$ and hence $x\not\in f^{-1}([n,n+1)$, while for $n=\lfloor f(x)\rfloor$ we have $n\ge 0$ because $f$ is non-negative, and $n<\infty$ since $f(x)<\infty$, so $f(x)\chi_{f^{-1}([n,n+1)}(x)=f(x)$ because $f(x)\in[n,n+1)$ and thus $x\in f^{-1}([n,n+1))$. If we have $f(x)=\infty$, then we have $f(x)\not\in[n,n+1)$ for all $n\ge 0$ and thereby $x\not\in f^{-1}([n,n+1))$, which shows that $f(x)\chi_{f^{-1}([n,n+1)}(x)=0$. In total, this gives $f\chi_{f^{-1}([0,\infty))}=f\chi_{f^{-1}([n,n+1))}$.

Comment: Still not understanding how they’re equal at points where $f(x)= \infty $

Comment: We use the conventions $1\cdot\infty=\infty$ and $0\cdot\infty=0$. Let $x\in[0,1]$ be such that $f(x)=\infty$. If we have $x\not\in[n,n+1)$, we have $f(x)\chi_{f^{-1}([n,n+1))}(x)=\infty\cdot 0=0$, otherwise we have $f(x)\chi_{f^{-1}([n,n+1))}(x)=\infty\cdot 1=\infty$.

Comment: But if $f(x)= \infty $ then $f(x)>n+1$ so surely $\chi_{f^{-1}([n,n+1))}(x)=0 $ since $ x $ is not in $f^{-1}([n,n+1)) $

Comment: Oh my god, of course, thanks for pinting it out. I was just resistant to reading it properly.

Comment: The question assumes that the function is nonnegative

Comment: I adjusted the answer, explaining in detail why you are right, for slow burners like myself :-)